# Accepting answers : What to do when your question asked to check your solution to a problem?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I asked this question a few days back.

[An argument with my friend over $\bigcup [a+\frac{1}{n},b]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/941753/an-argument-with-my-friend-over-bigcup-a-frac1n-b)

I had asked this question to know whether I was right in my approach, which other users approved to be correct. Now as you can see I have two answers to the question.

On what basis should I mark the question solved. I mean, ofcourse, the question was never unsolved, (and leaving a question with a solution marked unsolved doesn't seem right), but which answer do I mark as accepted answer? Thanks. :)

Comment: Which one helped to convince your friend? (Or did you just stop being friends with him? :-))

Comment: I didn't get a chance to tell him the given answers. He called me that night to tell me he understood my argument.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You question/request was

> Please clarify if I'm doing a blunder somewhere. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

You should accept the answer that you best feel answers this question/request.